# Class method naming issues - conflicts with extended class?

Tags: php, class

This is less of an issue, and more of a best practice question - I know these are subject to opinion, but I'm sure there must be a standard convention for this particular problem.

Let's say I've got two classes, `Account` and `Associate`.

`Account` contains several methods which are useful to `Associate`, and so naturally I'd extend the `Account` class to `Associate`.

However, an issue of course arises when I have two methods with the same name e.g. `create()`.

So far to counteract this instead of extending the parent class, I've been instantiating it as a variable in the child classes `__construct()` method, and then calling methods through that, e.g. `$this->Account->create();`.

Is there another way, e.g. a norm for using an extended classes methods while still having a method of the same name in the child class?

Any answers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: since we dont know about your domain is i doubt anybody cant answer your question faithfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Account contains several methods which are useful to Associate, and so naturally I'd extend the Account class to Associate.

No, this is not naturally, you are misusing inheritance. Or would you say that an associate **is an** account? If it **has an** account, use composition. If not, but the account class has methods that are useful for the associate class, they probably shouldn't be in the account class at all. Extract them to one or more other classes which can be used by both, Account and Associate.

Comment: You're right about misuse of inheritance. However in my case, an associate is one of many types of account which I believe should all share base methods, e.g. for sessions/password hashing etc - perhaps I'm wrong here?. There is no "account" type of account :)

Comment: Then it depends on how you see it: If `Associate` is just a **type** of `Account`, the `Account` class could have an aggregated `$type` attribute (and `Associate` will implement an `AccountType` interface).

Answer (score 0):

The child class method will be called using `$this` if you are within the child class methods. If you want the parent method though, you'd call `parent::create();` from within the child method.

But that is if you absolutely need to extend the Account class, which sounds unnecessary. If the "Account" class has public methods then you don't need to extend it, you can just call them after instantiating the class:

```
$account = new Account();
$account->create();
```

Or, if it is a public static method:

```
$creation = Account::create();
```